# Generating an X.509 certificate for FTP-over-SSL on Freenas

Tags: ftp, certificate, freenas, ssl-certificate, ftps

i've been Googling around for a moment on how to create a X.509 PEM certificate and private key for the FTP function in Freenas. I know i can use SFTP but i want to be able to secure the regular FTP protocol using FTP-over-SSL also. I have found how to generate SSH keys and other stuff but nothing specific for X.509 in PEM format.

I would prefer to generate these keys using a website or GUI if possible. I know my way round CLI's but that doesn't mean that i'm a fan of them :)

I have Freenas 0.7.2 Sabanda (revision 5543) which runs on FreeBSD 7.3-RELEASE-p3 (revision 199506).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this:

http://devsec.org/info/ssl-cert.html

And it worked with a self-signed certificate. Turned out i had to Google for "generate PEM" and not "generate x.509".

Answer (score 0):

Create a DSA key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa

Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_dsa):
```

Enter a different file in which to save the key in. Note this is asking for the name of a file, not the name of the directory, it will also create a `.pub` file, this is the public key for the above private key.